# How to partly initialize c++ objects when I don't need all values from the database?

Tags: c++, oop, optimization, constructor, initialization

I’m trying to cut down on the amount of network queries in my c++ program (to increase speed), and when displaying search results, I don’t want each (of the sometimes thousands) of objects found in the search to initialize themselves completely from the database when I only need to display part of this information.

It is much faster to perform one bigger query where I get all the information I want to display about the objects at once in the query (for example, for each object/row I select the id, the name and the location), passing them to a bigger constructor, and letting all other members be default values. Previously, and in other cases where I need the complete object, I just pass the ID to the object, then call initializeFromDatabase() directly to set all the other values.

```
//current solution (problem is, I might need many constructors like this for different purposes)
auto *myobject = new MyObject(345, "ObjectName", "Europe");
//no further (costly) initialization since I only need the following 2 values for my search results.
myobject->getName();
myobject->getLocationName();

//prevous solution (resulting in too many queries)
auto *myobject = new MyObject(345);
myobject->initializeFromDatabase();
myobject->getName();
myobject->getLocationName();
//I could also query the other 30 or so members here, everything is set.
```

This doesn’t feel like good practice though, I would need other custom constructors for say, another search window displaying other kinds of data about the objects.

Are there any general best practices / a suitable design pattern to solve this sort of problem? Should I create a “Search object” that is its own class and that can then be used to create the complete object when needed? Or always initialize with only the database ID (setting a flag that the object is not initialized yet) and use the setters I need?

Comment: Not sure what you asking for exactly. You need to provide the code i guess and point out your issue better perhaps. It's too broad atm. eg. you mention 2 or 3 different issues (even if related). Also this is somewhat related to cursor's (assuming SQL dbs). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(databases).

Comment: its more a question about how to best initialize an object with just the values I need at the moment (quering for the complete object at all times is too inefficient), I don't really need help with the SQL related part. I've changed the title to try to reflect this and added some example code. Is it still confusing? In that case I'll try to isolate the problem better...

Answer (score 0):

I found that a solution to this would be to use some sort of Lazy Loading, since I want to quickly load part of the object for the list, then load all of it if a user clicks on one of the objects. For example, a Virtual Proxy or the Ghost Design pattern would be suitable. I simply create a proxy object for displaying the search results (and for other lists in the program) that can create the full object on demand. Every proxy object has one constructor so I avoid the problem of using lots of different constructors for different purposes.

See Chapter 11 of Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture by Martin Fowler (published by Addison-Wesley Professional, 2002)